# Magento 2: Set all option selected in multiselect UI form?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, ui

```
<field name="customer_group">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Customer Group</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">popup</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_group</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass ids as below:

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">1,2,3</item>
```

Comment: can we pass this from Options source file?